# Where to put `beforeEach` for all test cases?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

What's the difference between these two tests:

```js
beforeEach(doSomething)

describe("i am the only root describe in this test file", () => {
    // many test cases...
})
```

```js
describe("i am the only root describe in this test file", () => {
    beforeEach(doSomething)
    // many test cases...
})
```

Comment: Describe creates a closure for tests. BeforeEach will run before every test for all these inner tests. In first example, writing beforeEach would execute once (not sure though)

Answer (score 1):

If put `beforeEach` in a describe, it runs before each test in this block. If put it in the root level, it runs before all tests in all test files.

See https://github.com/demo-drive-learn/mocha-root-pre-hook, or check this [demo](https://github.com/demo-drive-learn/mocha-root-pre-hook).